# multimap upper_bound return confusion

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I have a multimap filled with pairings. I want to iterate through a range. upper_bound does not return an iterator pointing to an element unless it find the first element whose key is greater than the value passed to upper_bound.

How can I tell if there was no value returned from upper_bound because there's nothing greater than the passed value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70ew3k67.aspx)

upper_bound returns the first element that is greater than your key value, if there is no element then it will return the same as `end()`

So you can just compare this against the end of your multimap

```
auto it = my_multi_map.upper_bound(some_val);
if (it == my_multi_map.end())
{
  // iterator is pointing past end so no value found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least if memory serves, if upper_bound doesn't find an element with a key larger than what you passed it, it'll return `container.end()`. This is fine for iterating with, as the norm for a pair of iterators is the beginning and one past the end of the range, so you can use `container.end()` as the end of a range without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

`upper_bound` is actually perfect for iterating, because it points to the element just after the end of the range - just like `end` does. So you form your loop similarly.

```
for (auto it = mymap.lower_bound(start_key), end = mymap.upper_bound(end_key); it != end; ++it)
```

If you only want a single key, pass the same value to `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, or use `equal_range` to get both at once. If the value doesn't exist in the map at all, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` will be equal and the loop won't execute.

Comment: but you check upper_bound() each loop.
it would be better to get upper_bound() only once (before looping)